# Getting 403 error while accessing "https://www.sec.gov/" from AWS even after specifying user agent

Tags: amazon-web-services, user-agent, http-status-code-403, sec

Response from [SEC.GOV](https://www.sec.gov/) for GET request:

> Your request has been identified as part of a network of automated
> tools outside of the acceptable policy and will be managed until
> action is taken to declare your traffic.Please declare your traffic by
> updating your user agent to include company specific information.

I'm getting 403 error even after adding user-agent in get request. I'm able to access sec.gov from local and Azure cloud without any issues. This is happening only in AWS since last 4-5 days. Not sure why? Any help appreciated!

Here's what I'm doing:

```html
import requests

url_1 = 'https://www.sec.gov'
url_2 = 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/0001781258/000178125821000028/0001781258-21-000028-index.html'

HEADERS = {'User-Agent': 'TEST'}

# Both of the below get requests gives 403 error
print(requests.get(url_1, headers=HEADERS))
print(requests.get(url_2, headers=HEADERS))
```

Comment: Have you tried a valid user agent instead of "TEST"?

Comment: I did, but still same error

Answer (score 1):

Check this link: https://www.sec.gov/os/webmaster-faq#user-agent

Here I am using PHP & CURL and resolved it with the following code:

```
$curl_headers   = array(    'User-Agent: MyDomainName.com info@MyDomainName.com',
                            'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate',
                            'Host: www.sec.gov');
$ch             =   curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $curl_headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "MyDomainName.com info@MyDomainName.com");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$html           =   curl_exec($ch);    
curl_close($ch);
```